# Recursive types with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I'd like to create a type which is an object containing either a string or an object which contains a string or an object, ...

So what I did is creating a type like this:

```js
type TranslationObject = { [key: string]: string | TranslationObject };
```

But when using it within reduce, that's where it's causing an error

```js
Object.keys(newTranslations).reduce((acc: TranslationObject, translationKey: string): TranslationObject => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [translationKey]: {
        ...acc[translationKey] as TranslationObject,
        [namespace]: {
          ...(acc[translationKey][namespace] as TranslationObject), // Error at this line
          ...newTranslations
        }
      }
    }
  }, translations);
```

The error is

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'string | TranslationObject'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'string | TranslationObject'.
```

So my type is either having as type a string or an object, but in that case, I'd like it to be the object part and I can't really figure it out.

Comment: Do you need an `as TranslationObject` after `acc[translationKey]` so that you're not trying to index something that might be a string using a string key?
So `((acc[translationKey] as TranslationObject)[namespace] as TranslationObject)` at the problem line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add as TranslationObject after acc[translationKey] since you can not try get a key from a string.

```
Object.keys(newTranslations).reduce((acc: TranslationObject, translationKey: string): TranslationObject => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [translationKey]: {
        ...acc[translationKey] as TranslationObject,
        [namespace]: {
          ...((acc[translationKey] as TranslationObject)[namespace] as TranslationObject), 
          ...newTranslations
        }
      }
    }
  }, translations);
```